# Typewriter making div move on smaller devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a problem, on smaller devices the div is moving as the script writes the text, and this is terrible, if I browse the website, the screen is moving. Is the problem with the CSS configuration? I've seen a lot of websites use typewriter and none of that happens, I really don't know how to fix it, I've tried using `position` but I haven't been successful

Could someone please help me with this? When using the browser developer tool you can see the problem, the screen moves when the script writes

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
        .box section div {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            margin: 35px 0px;
        }

        .section {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 135px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .text {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-content: center;
        }


        #app {
            font-size: 38px !important;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            line-height: 34px;
            padding-bottom: 24p;
        }

        @media (max-width:500px) {

            .box section div {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .box {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .text {
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
            }
        }

        .bg-black {
            background-color: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="box bg-black">
        <section class="section">
            <div>
                <div class="text">
                    <div id="app">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>


    <div>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>

    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = document.getElementById('app');

        var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
            loop: true,
            delay: 75,
        });

        typewriter
            .pauseFor(1500)
            .typeString('I am ')
            .pauseFor(400)
            .typeString('<strong>Developer</strong>')
            .pauseFor(1500)
            .deleteChars(9)
            .typeString('<strong>Designer</strong>')
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .deleteChars(8)
            .typeString('<strong>Sculptor</strong>')
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .deleteChars(8)
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .start();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, You gave padding in section class. That's why your div is moving in smaller screens.
Please remove padding from section class Or you can give padding in percentage instead of pixels and remove display: flex from media query.

```
.section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
@media (max-width:500px) {
    .box section div {
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Complete example

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
        .box section div {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            margin: 35px 0px;
        }

        .section {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .text {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-content: center;
        }


        #app {
            font-size: 38px !important;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            line-height: 34px;
            padding-bottom: 24p;
        }

        @media (max-width:500px) {

            .box section div {
         
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .box {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .text {
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
            }
        }

        .bg-black {
            background-color: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="box bg-black">
        <section class="section">
            <div>
                <div class="text">
                    <div id="app">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>


    <div>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Some text</h3>

    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = document.getElementById('app');

        var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
            loop: true,
            delay: 75,
        });

        typewriter
            .pauseFor(1500)
            .typeString('I am ')
            .pauseFor(400)
            .typeString('<strong>Developer</strong>')
            .pauseFor(1500)
            .deleteChars(9)
            .typeString('<strong>Designer</strong>')
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .deleteChars(8)
            .typeString('<strong>Sculptor</strong>')
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .deleteChars(8)
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .start();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```